# How to have 2 diff. environment variables in database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my production `database.yml`, I want the DB pool to be read from the environment variable `POOL1` if it exists. Otherwise, use `POOL2`. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work, as it can't be parsed:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  timeout: 20000
  encoding: unicode
  database: db
  pool: <%= ENV["POOL1'] or ENV['POOL2'] %>
```

Comment: `pool` should be an integer that represents the size of the pool, not the pool to connect to.  Example: `pool: 5`. The reason it cannot parse your code is that you've got mismatched single and double quotes.

Comment: OK, it's still an environment variable though. How do I do what I want?

Comment: You’ve got your quotes mixed up, should be `ENV["POOL1"]` (you have an `"` and an `'`).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the existence of `ENV` variables the same way you check for any other variables.

```
irb(main):003:0> ENV["foo"] = "1"
=> "1"
irb(main):004:0> ENV["bar"] || ENV["foo"]
=> "1"
```

So in your code, this should work.

```
pool: <%= ENV["POOL1"] || ENV["POOL2"] %>
```